# Java unsatisfied link error no HelloWorld in java.library.path

Tags: java-native-interface

while trying to run the jni hello world program in eclipse i got the following error

on in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no HelloWorld in java.library.path

```
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at HelloWorld.<clinit>(HelloWorld.java:11)
```

BUT I WORKED PERFECTLY IN COMMAND LINE

can anyone suggest me a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should happen because when you run your Java program, it cannot find the `HelloWorld` shared library (`.dll`, `.so`... depending on your OS).

Try this to check where the JVM expects you to put the shared library, and place it in one of the directories you see:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
```

Generally, the working directory is a safe choice.

Comment: I got 
Native code library failed to load.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no HelloWorld in java.library.path
after keeping shared library(HelloWorld.dll) in java.library.path